# Is there a Perl interactive shell (REPL) that can handle continuing lines?

Tags: perl

Matt Trout's [overview](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-17/) of interactive shells for Perl lists five choices for Perl interactive shells, and I've tried most of them. But not one can handle continuing lines, for example:

```pl
open my $f, "foo" ||
    die "Cannot open 'foo': $!";
```

This is a very common Perl idiom so it's annoying that I can't copy-and-paste most of the code from my editor.

Is there a REPL, or maybe a plugin for [`Reply`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Reply) or [`Devel::Repl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL) that can handle continuing lines?

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that a [CPAN search](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=REPL&mode=module) comes up with is [`Repl::Loop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Repl::Loop). Does that work for you?

Comment: No, because it's a Lisp interpreter in Perl, not a *Perl interactive shell*.